# combobox automatically populated with same value for all bound records

Tags: vb.net, forms, navigation

I created a Windows form (DateRowView) where all form fields are bound to an underlying database table (MS Access).  When I navigate to the next record, one form field in particular (combobox) automatically populates with the previous record's value.  This happens when the underlying database field is empty.  If the underlying field contains a value, the proper value displays.  No other form fields (textbox, checkbox, date) exhibit this behavior.  The underlying table values are correct; it's just what is displayed on the form that is incorrect.  This is a VB.NET application, Visual Studio 2019, MS Access 2016.  Any help/guidance will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the method where you're loading/binding the record, and sample records?

Comment: What is `forms` here (have you read the tag description)? You need to properly identify your platform. e.g., `winforms` (desktop development).

Comment: Are the controls bound in the designer or in code?

Comment: What is the `DropDownStyle` property of that `ComboBox` set to? If it is `DropDown` then the control can contain text that doesn't match and item. It ought to be `DropDownList`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your responses. After much troubleshooting, I stumbled upon the solution. It turns out the combobox 'DropDownStyle' property was the culprit. I had originally set the property to 'DropDownList' to prevent users from entering a value. When I set the property to 'DropDown,' the problem went away. I have no idea why this property would have any effect on record navigation, but it does.